# Finding private API keys for iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, reverse-engineering

I've been conducting quite a few `MITM` attacks as of late on my iPhone with [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). Many of the apps that I've been yearning to get a better understanding of are easy to reverse engineer simply using `cURL` to mimic the requests that are being sent to the server. Others however, require a signature that I'm guessing uses a secret key that is used to generate a hash of the payload. When I reverse engineered Instagram's API a while back, it went something like this

```
function GenerateSignature($data) {
    return hash_hmac('sha256', $data, 'b4a23f5e39b5929e0666ac5de94c89d1618a2916');
}

$data = '{"device_id":"'.$device_id.'","guid":"'.$guid.'","password":"'.$pass.'","username":"'.$username.'","email":"'.$email.'","_csrftoken":"c3a1648209b1eeefd7bd8d404211be5e", "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}';  
$sig = GenerateSignature($data);
$new_data = 'signed_body='.$sig.'.'.urlencode($data).'&ig_sig_key_version=4';
```

And then, obviously the query string would be sent along with the request to the server. But, I can't seem to find the API key using Charles for an app that I'm really interested in. My iPhone is jailbroken, but I'm not quite sure where to look inside of the `var/mobile/applications` folder to find the API key? Any ideas?

Comment: If there's a key in the app, then you need to use the standard set of tools - disassembly, breakpoints on hashing methods or the request to determine the key that is being used.

Comment: Elaborate some more. Because, I've looked at the requests (all of which have signatures) but can't seem to find the key.

Comment: Dude, it's work. You have to back track the code to the point where it generates the signature and then extract the from that.

Comment: Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://code.google.com/p/droidbox/ to find the key. Or use a Java disassembly tool.

There is also a webservice where you can upload an APK and scan it for malware. The report includes ADB logcat output with the key, for example see this [scan-report](http://apkscan.nviso.be/report/show/5019f9aab6dc9580590f9e36fd9cf453) (scroll to the bottom "Output generated by ADB logcat").